# SQL Query to filter the values according to preferences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in both the table common field name is SID

Table1:

```
sp       id
ram      1
varun    2
santosh  3
krishnan 4
```

Table2:

```
id    wv    rf
1     6.2   1.2
1     3.2   1.4
1     1.4   5.2
1     1.5   3.2
2     5.4   6.2
2     3.5   6.3
```

I want to filter the rows in the second table where ID value of both tables are matched, if i select ram in sp it will display the values of id =1 in wv and rf in table 2.
How to make query for this, Is there any examples ple sensd me...

Comment: I don't see SID in your tables

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit better please? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Refer this : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this

```
SELECT T1.sp,T2.wv,T2.rf 
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
```

**[Joins Between Tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html)**

**Update**

```
SELECT T1.sp,T2.wv,T2.rf 
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
WHERE T1.sp='ram'
```

Comment: sir if i select ram from sp column in table 1 in query it will display the values of wv and rf in Table 2 using matched id values in both the table... How to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select s.sp, p.wv, p.rf 
from table1 s 
inner join table2 p 
    on s.id=p.id
```

Comment: sir if i select ram from sp column in table 1 in query it will display the values of wv and rf in Table 2 using matched id values in both the table... How to do it...